# AngularJS: Correct minify-able syntax when using resolve with controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I'm using the resolve functionality with a couple of controllers to fetch some data before the rendering of a new view kicks in like this:

```
HomeCtrl.resolve = {
    pictures: function(Picture) {
        return Picture.getall();
    } 
};
```

How do I write this so the Picture-service, that is passed as an argument, doesn't get overwritten when minified?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can inject the dependencies using the following pattern, it is minification proof

```
HomeCtrl.resolve = {
    pictures : ['Picture', function(Picture) {
                return Picture.getall();
            }]
};
```

Comment: any place where angular uses DI, you can use this syntax

Comment: Sadly, It's not working for me. HomeCtrl.resolve = {
    pictures : ['$q', function(a) {}]
}; will report Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Comment: @wukong If you need to inject the `$q` service you should do it like this `HomeCtrl.resolve = {pictures: ['$q', function($q) {}]}`, if you need to inject the `$q` service AND an `a` service, you should do it like this `HomeCtrl.resolve = {pictures: ['$q', 'a', function($q, a) {}]}` .

Comment: @acrmuui sry, it's my fault. The solution works. My code is something like `HomeCtrl.resolve =  ['$q', function($q) {}]`. I expect angular is smart enough to handle this situation because I only have one dependency to resolve. It turns out that since `resolve` is array and aslo an object. Angular will treat it as a regular object! It is hard to find out the problem because the code will work without minify. From angular's perspective, the object is `{"0":"$q","1":function ($q){}}`. We need to wrap the function with `{something: ["$q", function ($q){}]}`.

Comment: why do the tuts not say this?! i completely forgot about DI issues!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make resolve function minification safe:

```
HomeCtrl.resolve = {
    pictures: getPictures
};

getPictures.$inject = ['Picture'];
function getPictures(Picture){
    return Picture.getall();
}
```

This technique takes advantage of the fact that in javascript functions are also objects and, therefore, can have properties.

For more information, go to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di and search for "$inject".